# RouteConfig but keep MVC routing

Tags: asp.net-core, angular, angular2-routing

In a basic ASP.NET Core 1 / MVC 6 app and an Angular 2 component, I have this RouteConfig which works good :

```
@RouteConfig([
        { path: '/Product', as: 'Product', component: GenericDetails }
    ])
```

I have some questions about that :

1. With Angular 2 routing, can we still call an MVC route, and let the server choose the Controller + View to render ? If it's possible, what about the component specified in the RouteConfig ? Is it bootstrapped automatically ?
2. If we choose the MVC routing, must we remove completly the Angular routing of our component ?
3. If so, what is the best solution to call the MVC route ?

Thanks